Getting part of a SAML object in c#
I have an ASP.NET Core app, and I am trying to set up a SAML 2.0 login system.
When I connect to the IdP, I get this object back:
saml2AuthnResponse.ClaimsIdentity.Claims;

And when I look through it, I see this:
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: AAdzZWNyZXQxO1n4bE5XWDad/3XvgMDg9TRA8wIG9saVhmfGWFNpbu28iA/ts/EfK7S+XB9oNoOe6pBmGA8zZkOWTmZpQ9amrRjCto1MFw2/MlBF10geQZwqxv+d2f2+lz/fIoqx9DE=


workflowid: 05
urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6: JRR3@SETI.ORG

What I need is the email part, JRR3@SETI.ORG
How do I get that part though?
I know I can write it out as I did, but I just need the email, not the whole part that starts with urn:oid...
Is there a way to capture that?
Thanks!

Try "tokenizing".
string s = "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.5923.1.1.1.6: JRR3@SETI.ORG";

string email = s.Split( new char[] { ' ' } ).Last();

Debug.Assert( email.Contains( "@" ) );

Console.WriteLine( email );
Console.ReadKey();

